# Building a Kindle reader like interface on Android

Tags: android

Kindle reader has a unique interface compared to all other reading apps. It takes a very large text and show it on screen in such a way that you dont have to scroll but you have to swipe to go to the next page. It reduces the text to be shown on the screen based on the screen size.

I have tried a lot but I am not able to see how they do it. There are number of questions on SO related to this but none of those answered were satisfactory. In many cases the problem is solved by adjusting the font of the text rather than text.

I think the correct approach to achieve this would be the following but I am not sure if all of it is possible in Android.

1. Create a Buffered reader and read each character.
2. Go on adding that character to the TextView
3. Check if the character is going beyond the visible area.
4. If yes stop and wait for the flick action else go to step1

If anyone can tell me how to achieve point 3 in android rest should be easy. Feel free to suggest other alternatives as well as long as they are not above web view.

Comment: I think they know how many characters will make a page full because they know font size, page size and other such things. So they show that many characters. I don't think they use  TextView at all, they are probably drawing in a custom View's canvas.

Comment: I have seen the implementation of another ebook reader. They did it with native code (NDK) + Open GL canvas. I don't think you can do this with TextView efficiently.

Comment: Okay. I will try it out with Canvas in that case. Any ideas if Canvas will be faster than TextView ?